# What to use: .aspx or .html

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a website in .aspx, and while adding more pages I saw that I can choose for an .aspx-extension and for a .html-extension.

I am a bit confused at the moment. Normally I am using always the .aspx one, but what is the difference between them and which of them do you guys prefer me to use?

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you referring to `.cshtml` or `.vbhtml`?

Answer (score 3):

This is the biggest challenge for the beginners. Aspx pages and asp.net `webservercontrols` are like machines that spit out html. if you want a logic to spit html on the page according to that logic then use `.aspx` or `Webservercontrols` on that page. if you don't have very serious decisions to make programmatically and need straight forward html that does not change based on some events then use `.html` pages. But if you are on something like asp.net then it means you may have to make decisions based on data from the server so in that case `.aspx` would be requirement than an option.

Comment: unless you use the "static" html as a template to be controlled by data received from the server using a javascript setup.... too many possibilities to say one is required when "X". I'd agree it is more preference than anything. each has their pros and cons and the decision depends on your coding and design decisions early on.

Comment: In my opinion it is more convenient to to handle logic in aspx than with javascript or others. Aspx is more like about code reusability. Why not to take advantage of the logic on aspx than try to rewrite it and get lost in things that already exists and are easy to use.

Comment: A good point, and I am not quick to dismiss it. I would also present that by my experience, writing specific code results in a lighter application. .aspx are great at what they do, but definitely not required for building a complex data centered application by any means. It is bit harder in some cases, and even more so when you catch yourself reinventing the wheel. It's a dicision based on perspective

Comment: hmmm.. I am sure here everyone has got his own stand point. I have great concern for the beginners and I too had such questions in the beginning of my asp.net career. I often wondered why there is webservercontrols when there are html tags already available. That  triggered my response here. I agree with you that there a lot negative and positive points that can't be discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

An HTML file can only contain **static content** (it can not contain any **server side code**), it will not be processed by the ASP.NET pipeline.

So normally you should always use aspx files in an ASP.NET app, except if you have a page which only has to contain static HTML, that way you might *save some performance*, because IIS can directly serve that file without running it through the whole pipeline.

Comment: That is correct, you can mix and match the two in the same project.

Comment: This isn't true in all cases. Any file extension can be processed by ASP.NET.

Comment: It's not true. You may define in web.config any extension for the asp.net work.

Answer (score 1):

.htm/l files are *generally* used for static markup, but they can be .NET-enabled also (using configuration options). That is to say, other extensions can be compiled and run through the ASP.NET ISAPI handler to be pages that have code-behind and managed controls and "do stuff" server-side.

I guess it's preference, so you could decide to use .htm/l for server-handled pages and .aspx for handled pages. I personally don't find this option appealing and have to deal with, at least weekly, an .htm/l page that *didn't* need any .NET stuff but now does. It doesn't make sense to me to mix up the files like this - the effort for IIS should be negligible, particularly for .aspx pages that contain only static content. It's much less effort than having to wonder about changing file names (and therefore URLs or rewrites) or setting global configuration options to handle certain extensions because modifications were needed.